# The $2$'nd law when a subsystem's entropy decreases due to a measurement?

Tags: thermodynamics, measurements, density-operator

### Background

So let's say there's system $1$ and system $2$ where system $1+2$ is an isolated system.

Let the density matrix of system $2$ be:

$$\rho_2 =  
\begin{pmatrix} 
3/4 & 1/4 \\
1/4 & 1/4 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Using $S = - k_b \text{Tr}(\rho_2 ln \rho_2) \approx \frac{3}{2}k_b$. But let's say system $1$ performs a measurement on system $2$, on some basis such that the projection operator is

$$P_i = |a \rangle\langle a | =  
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The new density operator is given by:

$$
 \rho _{2}'={\frac {P_{i}\rho P_{i}}{\operatorname {tr} [\rho P_{i}]}}=  \frac{1}{4}
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1/4 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now, the change in entropy in system $2$ has decreased $\Delta S \approx -1.5 k_b$. Now, since the $2$'nd law of thermodynamics states the entropy of an isolated system always increases. Hence, system $1$'s entropy must have increased! Note, the $2$'nd law would only suggest that the entropy would increase by about $1.5 k_b$.

### Question

So this is where I'm confused can the entropy of system $1$ increase more than $1.5 k_b$ solely due to the measurement?

Comment: How did you calculate $\ln \rho_2$?

Comment: Ah, I scribbled some calculations on pen and paper using the $\ln(1 -x)$ expansion and cut it off.

Comment: where $1$ becomes the identity in matrix language